# is this struct undefined behaviour from source file

Tags: c++, c++11, struct, g++, undefined-behavior

I have a struct from a source file s.cpp:

```
struct s{
unsigned long long a;
s(unsigned long long b){a=b;}
unsigned long long get(){return a;}
};
```

And in main file, compiled of course with g++ main.cpp s.cpp brief syntax

```
struct s{
s(unsigned long long b);
unsigned long long get();
};

s s1(123456);
//some code
unsigned long long c=s1.get();
```

Now I know it will not compile returning undefined reference, wich is a shame. Have to define ctor and get(), outside of brackets in s.cpp. I wonder if there's a g++ flag to possibly not having to.
But the main question is, is the s1.get() safe or is undefined behaviour?

**EDIT**

Thanks for your responses, but I still don't understand well the mechanism.
So in this case in s.cpp:

```
struct teste{
    int a=0;
    teste(int b);
    int g();
};
teste::teste(int b){a+=b;}
int teste::g(){ return a;}
```

and in main:

```
struct teste{
    int c=1;
    teste(int b);
    int g();
};

teste ato(8);
printf("\n%d",ato.g());
```

Considering the memory allocation, shouldn't return 9 instead of 8 as it actual perform?
Even if I change c to a, making it exactly equal but the 1, it seems to look always for the a and its init value from s.cpp always.
Sugesting that declaration of other thing than method to main is superflous.

Comment: Shouldn't `get` have a return type?

Comment: right forget to put it, will edit, thanks

Comment: That violates [One definition rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule)

Comment: Where is init()? Do you mean the ctor?

Comment: yes, sorry, the ctor.

Answer (score 2):

You have a strange mix of declarations and definitions.

First, it looks like your class declaration (which you should put in a header file, to be included in `main`) should look something like this:

```
struct s
{
  unsigned long long a;
  s(unsigned long long b);
  unsigned long long get();
};
```

Then, your implementations should look something like

```
s::s(unsigned long long b) a(b) {}

unsigned long long  s::get() { return a; }
```

Comment: Yes, I know that, but what I'm asking is if it is possible to omit the a declaration in main file. I tested and it works. But I suspect that's undefined behaviour.

Comment: @user2170324: It is very much undefined behavior.  The compiler doesn't know how much storage to allocate for an instance of `struct S`.  Formally you get undefined behavior, practically you find that the member functions' idea of where their member variables are stored overlaps with some other object.

Comment: @user2170324 no, you can't do that, you need the declaration of you want to construct an `s` instance. The compiler needs to know the size and data layout of `s`.

Comment: I suspected that. I wonder why it works... Makes sense. It will overlap sometime.

Comment: So there is no way to call just a method without including all the header?

Comment: I mean the complete declaration. As I'm understanding, it must have the same layout everywhere.

Comment: @user2170324 a single non-member function, yes. But instantiating a class is quite different to that.

Comment: @juanchopanza I thought the only difference between class and struct is that the struct have all members public.

Comment: @user2170324 class/struct has nothing to do with it. My previous comment applies to both, because both are the same.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not safe -- if you can manage to get it to compile, it's undefined behavior.  It directly violates the **One Definition Rule**, in particular C++03 §3.2/5, which says:

> There can be more than one definition of a class type (clause 9), [...] , in a program provided that each
>   definition appears in a different translation unit, and provided the definitions satisfy the following requirements.
>   Given such an entity named `D` defined in more than one translation unit, then
>   — each definition of `D` shall consist of the same sequence of tokens; and
>   *... More conditions omitted ...*
>
> [...] If the
>   definitions of `D` satisfy all these requirements, then the program shall behave as if there were a single
>   definition of `D`. If the definitions of D do not satisfy these requirements, then the behavior is undefined.

Since your two class definitions do *not* consist of the same sequence of tokens, the behavior is undefined.

The C++11 behavior is identical here.

Comment: I am not sure this applies. The difference is not in the tokes of the class definition, but in the presence of the definitions of the member functions inlined inside the class. But there is a thin line here.

Comment: I have edited the question, can you confirm that the second exxample is indeed defined or undefined behaviour?

Comment: @user2170324: First of all, your code still doesn't compile since it's invalid syntax to write `int a=0;` or `int c=1;` in the `struct` body definition.  Secondly, yes it's still undefined behavior because the two `struct` definitions **do not consist of the same sequence of tokens**.

Comment: It does compile! In g++ c++1 at least it does. And works well so far. I haven't said why I do want this. Well, it's because a type from an include that is too heavy, ages to compile. Then, with this approach, I include that header only on s.cpp. It work like charm! And about undefined behaviour, well aren't we testing the behaviour? As I said, with eyes to read and head to understand, It seems that declaration of other thing than ctor and method outside src, is superfluos if you dont need to access it outside. Thats the behaviour of g++11

Comment: @user2170324: No, we aren't "testing" the behavior.  **Undefined behavior is still undefined.**  Anything can happen -- the program can crash, silently corrupt memory, send a nasty email to your boss, or erase your hard drive.  *It can also succeed silently with no ill effects*.  Those are all valid results that can happen when you invoke undefined behavior.  It's impossible to distinguish correct behavior with undefined behavior which appears to function correctly, so no amount of testing can determine if your code has defined behavior or not.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly, the question is whether it is legal to have the declaration and definition in one file and the different declaration in a different translation unit, compared to say having the declaration in a header file.

If, and only if, all of the declarations for the same type are exactly the same in all of the translation units <sup>*</sup>, then it is legal. But it will be error prone, if you modify one of the declarations, or any other change affects the exact definition you will break the ODR and cause undefined behavior.

<sup>*</sup>: Not only the declarations must be textually the same, but lookup for each one of the symbols must yield the same entities, and basically they must really refer to exactly one and only one thing.

Answer (score 0):

This issue here is that the member functions of `s` are implicitly defined `inline` in s.cpp. This restricts these member functions to only being defined in the translation unit for s.cpp. In main.cpp, the compiler only gets to see the declarations. Hence the linker error. (I believe this is referred to as having "internal linkage" or something like that, if someone could verify?).

As mentioned, moving the function's definition *outside* of `s` solve the compiler error. The reason is that the definitions are no longer `inline`. Thus, the definition can now be linked to and used in main.cpp. So the new code is well-defined c++.

The thing about `inline` functions is that they must be defined in every translation unit in which they are used. For this reason, `inline` functions are usually placed in a header file, so that a simple `#include` suffices.

Comment: My problem is not the compiler error... Please read the question again.

Comment: The fact that they are `inline` does not *restrict these member functions to only being defined in the translation unit s.cpp*, it only means that it is not considered a violation of the ODR if the same symbol is defined in multiple translation units.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two different structs with the same name, probably in the same namespace, which is likely to cause problems.

In s.cpp (I modified the code a bit to be easier to understand):

```
struct s{ //I'll refer to this struct as S1 below
    int _a;
    s(int a) : _a(a) {}
    int get() {return _a;}
};
```

In main.cpp

```
// you added this struct declaration because otherwise it desn't compile
// (providing there is no silly #include "s.cpp")
// But it actually declares ANOTHER struct called s as well
struct s{ // I will refer to this struct as S2 below
    s(int a);
    int get();
};

s my_s(123);
//some code
int c = my_s.get(); // the compiler checks that S2 contains a get function: OK
```

Now, what happens is that the linker will see two `s` symbols in the same namespace, and here start problems that will be really annoying to debug. You may get your `123` value back, everything seems to work fine but then you compile in release (or change the compiler, or change the platform, or restart your machine, or any other thing that you think shouldn't change the behaviour of your code) and it doesn't work anymore...

To avoid that kind of problem, when you want to use a struct, it needs to be declared before the line that uses it. Declare it in the s.h and define it in s.cpp (I guess that it is what you tried to do in your .cpp file but you need to define every function separately):

```
// s.h
struct s{
    unsigned long long a;

    s(unsigned long long b);
    unsigned long long get();
};

// s.cpp
s::s(unsigned long long b) : a(b) {}

unsigned long long s::get() { return a; }
```

Or inline everything in your .h file and include it in your main.cpp.

Comment: I don't have to if I include all directly in main. And that's not what I'm asking.

Comment: Do you want to know if you can use the `struct s` defined in s.cpp without adding the extra declaration (nor including the cpp file either of course) in main.cpp?

Comment: yes, the extra declaration being the unsigned long long a; I tested, it compiles and work, s1.get() returns it; But is this undefined behaviour?